# iOS distribution certificates expiring for two apps from same team: Do I need to take separate actions?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, keychain, certificate

I have two apps both associated with the same development team, and I've gotten notifications for both of them that `Your iOS Distribution Certificate will no longer be valid in 30 days`. I got these notifications for the two apps on separate days. I followed the instructions on [this page](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2020/08/26/how-to-generate-new-apple-developer-distribution-certificate/) and generated a new .p12 file, and now on `developer.apple.com` under `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` there's a new iOS Distribution Certificate for our team.

**What I Want To Know:** Do I need to take separate actions for each app, or is this all I need to do?

Comment: Check with Apple would seem to be the sensible course of action.

Comment: Wouldn’t this be more about how you are distributing those two apps? Since you didn’t link to apple KB I’ll at least do that in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Apple covers your next steps in the FAQ - https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/

**iOS Distribution Certificate (App Store)**

> If your Apple Developer Program membership is valid, your existing apps on the App Store won't be affected. However, you'll no longer be able to upload new apps or updates signed with the expired or revoked certificate to the App Store.

**iOS Distribution Certificate (in-house, internal-use apps)**

> Users will no longer be able to run apps that have been signed with this certificate. You must distribute a new version of your app that is signed with a new certificate